# Custom UITableViewCells are reused with identifier but without content in them

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom class `YouTubeCell` for cells in my `UITableView`. After I've written the code to populate cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView` I get the `if let` statement of cell to be nil (very weird, I know). So, cells are just white even if I've set them to be transparent (`UIColor.clearColor()`), but the `numberOfRowsInSection` is working properly (there are 6 elements, just as in an array). Any help appreciated.

Comment: thanks, Dragos just solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks very awkward. Maybe only you haven't assigned the class of UITableViewCell to be YouTubeCell as you have written in Identity Inspector. Everything else looks just fine.